# Single-Sign-On Environment with Identity Management

Tags: node.js, oauth, single-sign-on, identity-management

I want to built a SSO Service with nodejs.

I have been looking in oauth methods and passport examples, but did not come to a conclusion.

I want to have an Identity Server like https://id.mycompany.com, where the user can create and edit his profile. He also should see what services he can use from my company.

There will be another resource like https://app1.mycompany.com. If the user enters this page he will be redirected to id.mycompany.com to authenticate, and if so, he will be redirected back to app1 with access granted.

Is this an oauth2 mechanism? Because I don't want the user to decide if app1 gets access. I want to decide which user have access to resources of app1.

So I need kind of oauth, but without the client_id part in the redirect url, because I own all Servers.

Hope you can help me, or what I need to search for.

Comment: Since you are working on the same domain, I would just do authentication id.mycompany.com. Store the session in some central database. Redis is a good choice for this. Then when you redirect to app1.mycompany.com, just read off the cookie and do a look up in redis.

Comment: Or, you could checkout https://www.okta.com/ or https://stormpath.com/